# Filtering noise on vulnerable image OpenCV Python

Tags: opencv

I have an image I've process [weather map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WseYg.png), that contains weather front lines and some noises. I want filter that noises from the image, to only weather front lines left there.

I know, usually it's achieved by opencv opening function (cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN)), but in my case it not works, because lines I want to leave is so thin, so they are disappearing with the noise. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: connectedComponents or findContours. for each contour, get bounding box, assess the size of the bounding box, and if it's too small, erase that component/contour. that will leave large contours alone (even thin ones), while erasing small ones.

Comment: hey gregor, I would might go the easy way and combine: 
cv2.GaussianBlur and 
cv2.threshold